# Unity refuses to open 2 popup windows

Tags: c#, unity

So am am making a unity program, where if you click 2 different objects, 2 different windows are supposed to pop up.

To make them, I use private

```
private bool showPopUp = false;
private Rect rectangle = new Rect(int, int, int, int);
```

Both have a collider so that I can use OnMouseDown() to set showPopUp to true.

the onGUI class simply says

```
void OnGUI()
    {
        if (showPopUp)
        {
            rectangle = GUILayout.Window(0, rectangle, ShowGUI, "Prescription");
        }
    }
```

and my showGui looks like this

```
void ShowGUI(int windowID)
    {
      //some GUILayout things like textboxes and stuff are in here too

        GUILayout.BeginVertical();
            if (GUILayout.Button ("Okay"))//(GUI.Button(new Rect((Screen.width/4)-30, (float)(Screen.height/1.2)-30,60, 25), "OK"))
            {
                showPopUp = false;
            }
        GUILayout.EndVertical();

        GUI.DragWindow();
    }
}
```

These are two totally different classes, and on two completely different objects. However, if I have one of the popup windows open., and the to open the second, the first one goes blank, the second doesn't even show up, and I get this error:

> ArgumentException: GUILayout: Mismatched LayoutGroup.Repaint
>   UnityEngine.GUILayoutUtility.BeginLayoutGroup (UnityEngine.GUIStyle
>   style, UnityEngine.GUILayoutOption[] options, System.Type LayoutType)
>   (at
>   C:/BuildAgent/work/aeedb04a1292f85a/artifacts/EditorGenerated/GUILayoutUtility.cs:210)
>   UnityEngine.GUILayout.BeginHorizontal (UnityEngine.GUIContent content,
>   UnityEngine.GUIStyle style, UnityEngine.GUILayoutOption[] options) (at
>   C:/BuildAgent/work/aeedb04a1292f85a/artifacts/EditorGenerated/GUILayout.cs:235)

What do I need to change to allow me to open 2 windows at once?

Answer (score 2):

the problem is with

```
rectangle = GUILayout.Window(0, rectangle, ShowGUI, "Prescription");
```

since both of them have an ID of 0, unity tries to make 2 different windows with the same ID, causing a crash.

All you need to do is give one an ID of 0, the other an id of 1, so the other would look like

```
rectangle = GUILayout.Window(1, rectangle, ShowGUI, "Prescription");
```